# Getting weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Getting weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory** exception when deploying war file on weblogic server[12.2.1.4]

The same war file gets deployed without any issues on tomcat server manually and also within spring tool suite.

Using:- JDK 8.

1. Spring Boot - 2.7.11
2. Hibernate - 5.6.15.Final
3. Hibernate Validator - 6.2.5.Final
4. Spring Boot Starter Data JPA - 2.7.11

Note: pom.xml has dependency for persistence api coming from two jars:

1. javax.persistence.api[2.2] - hibernate core - 5.6.15.Final
2. jakarta.persistence.api[2.2.3] - spring boot starter data jpa

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here